# My code isn't coloured and my intellisense isn't working properly

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-2019

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class player : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space)) ;

    }
}
```

in the void update part of the code, my code is simply white and is not in different colours as it should have been as it was in the tutorial I was watching and my IntelliSense isn't suggesting me methods used in UNITY such as GetKeyDown, KeyCode etc. I use the community version of visual studio 2019. I tried updating visual studio but there was no change. It also takes a lot of time for Visual Studio to display the Code at first it only displays a blank screen and then after waiting for a few minutes it displays the code

Comment: How exactly do you open that file? By double click on it within Unity? And do you have `Visual Studio Tools for Unity` installed via the Visual Studio installer?

Comment: yes, I double click on it to open it and I have Visual Studio Tools for UNITY installed via Visual Studio installer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to set visual studio as your code editor unity.

Edit->Preferences->External Tools and in the dropdown set visual studio.

[image]